Msal logout asking to select account
I have created a code to automatically select the first account for logout but it is asking to select the account which we want to logout
if (accounts.length > 0) {
        const selectedAccount = accounts[0];
        console.log("Selected Account for logout: ", selectedAccount);
        
        instance.logoutRedirect({
          account: selectedAccount,
          
        });
      }
        
        setUser(''),
        localStorage.removeItem('userdetails'),
        setUserDetails(''),
        navigate('/')

